# How to use rest API to login facebook in android

Tags: java, android

I am currently working in a startup and my employer has asked me to login facebook in android using REST API. I have no idea what he is asking me to do and I read a lot on internet but I am still not clear about what to do and how to do. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What have you done so far?
This link might help you https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apis-and-sdks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Facebook SDK to add Facebook login button, or use OAuth2 for Facebook login. You can start from here: [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android)